# install grunt in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 14.04, nodejs, javascript, grunt

I am trying to install Grunt v1.0.0 in Ubuntu using this command

```
sudo npm -g install grunt
```

or

```
sudo npm -g install grunt@1.0.0
```

in both cases, I am getting

```
/usr/local/bin/grunt ->/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt/bin/grunt/usr/local/lib`-- grunt@1.0.1
```

I have installed Node.js version : 4.2 and Npm.

output of `npm list -g`

```
    /usr/local/lib
`-- grunt-cli@1.2.0
  +-- findup-sync@0.3.0
  | `-- glob@5.0.15
  |   +-- inflight@1.0.5
  |   | `-- wrappy@1.0.2
  |   +-- inherits@2.0.1
  |   +-- minimatch@3.0.2
  |   | `-- brace-expansion@1.1.5
  |   |   +-- balanced-match@0.4.1
  |   |   `-- concat-map@0.0.1
  |   +-- once@1.3.3
  |   `-- path-is-absolute@1.0.0
  +-- grunt-known-options@1.1.0
  +-- nopt@3.0.6
  | `-- abbrev@1.0.9
  `-- resolve@1.1.7
```

When I am hitting terminal with `user@super:~$grunt`

I am getting `command not found` response.

what wrong I am doing?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you installed Grunt globally via NPM, but did not install Grunt CLI, which puts the 'grunt' command in your system path. Try this:

`npm install -g grunt-cli`

See the documentation here: https://gruntjs.com/getting-started#installing-the-cli